# Point Grey Camera Driver Issue

Tags: ros, pointgrey, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use my point grey camera "Firefly MV"  working with ros

Running Ubuntu 16.04 on Nvedia TX1

Camera works fine using the pointgrey software (binaries) on this machine.

Launched the cmd:
roslaunch pointgrey_camera_driver camera.launch

[ERROR] [1490413273.037167925]: Failed to load nodelet [/camera/image_proc_debayer] of type [image_proc/debayer] even after refreshing the cache: Could not find library corresponding to plugin image_proc/debayer. Make sure the plugin description XML file has the correct name of the library and that the library actually exists.
[ERROR] [1490413273.037276049]: The error before refreshing the cache was: Could not find library corresponding to plugin image_proc/debayer. Make sure the plugin description XML file has the correct name of the library and that the library actually exists.
[FATAL] [1490413273.037801357]: Failed to load nodelet '/camera/image_proc_debayer`of type`image_proc/debayer`to manager`camera_nodelet_manager'
[camera/image_proc_debayer-3] process has died [pid 23867, exit code 255, cmd /home/ubuntu/drive/catkin_ws/devel/lib/nodelet/nodelet load image_proc/debayer camera_nodelet_manager __name:=image_proc_debayer __log:=/home/ubuntu/.ros/log/cf5bdaaa-1051-11e7-b5d5-00044b6696c8/camera-image_proc_debayer-3.log].
log file: /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/cf5bdaaa-1051-11e7-b5d5-00044b6696c8/camera-image_proc_debayer-3*.log

I'm thinking it's something to do w/ image_proc, So i've cloned the image pipeline git into catkin_ws/src and ran catkin make but the problem persists.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257851/point-grey-camera-driver-issue/) by [machinehum](https://answers.ros.org/users/29817/machinehum/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-03-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2017-04-04**:
What does it give you when you launch this: `rosrun pointgrey_camera_driver list_cameras`

**Comment by [machinehum](https://answers.ros.org/users/29817/machinehum/) on 2017-04-04**:
It listed the camera properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys I solved my own question - I ended up finding the binary for image pipeline.

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-image-pipeline
```

---

Originally posted by [machinehum](https://answers.ros.org/users/29817/machinehum/) with karma: 16 on 2017-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [staljbs](https://answers.ros.org/users/17761/staljbs/) on 2017-04-11**:
How did you solve the issue? I have the same issue that I have been trying to solve for a few days now.

$rosrun pointgrey_camera_driver list_cameras
Number of cameras found: 1
[0]Serial: 16493053, Model: Chameleon3 CM3-U3-50S5C, Vendor: Point Grey Research, Sensor: Sony IMX264 (2/3" Color CMOS)

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2017-10-16**:
What was the solution, please?

**Comment by [machinehum](https://answers.ros.org/users/29817/machinehum/) on 2017-10-16**:
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-image-pipeline

That's all - I just didn't know there was a binary.

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2017-10-17**:
So the driver http://wiki.ros.org/pointgrey_camera_driver works well in TX1 now?

**Comment by [machinehum](https://answers.ros.org/users/29817/machinehum/) on 2017-10-17**:
I got it to work